# how to animate from pandas x y coordinate timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, animation

say I have:

```
df ={'animal' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
     'x':[76.551, 77.529, 78.336,79.249,  76.077, 77, 78.02, 79.23, 77.733],
     'y': [151.933, 152.945, 153.970, 152.004, 153.027, 119.369, 120.615, 118.935, 119.115],
    'time': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3,2,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

how can I animate the trajectory of each `animal` (in different colours) according to the time and keep the previous trajectories on the graph (and ideally if there are overlapping trajectories, the latest one shows in front)?
This plots just the first animal:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.animation as animation 
import numpy as np 
%matplotlib notebook #to enable animation in jupyter notebook

fig = plt.figure() 
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(75, 80), ylim=(119, 155)) 
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2) 

# initialization function 
def init(): 
    # creating an empty plot/frame 
    line.set_data([], []) 
    return line, 

# lists to store x and y axis points 
xdata, ydata = [], [] 

# animation function 
def animate(i): 
    for animal, subdf in df.sort_values('time').groupby('animal'):
        xdata.append(subdf['x'])
        ydata.append(subdf['y'])
        line.set_data(xdata, ydata) 
        return line, 

# setting a title for the plot 
plt.title('') 
# hiding the axis details 
#plt.axis('off') 

# call the animator  
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, interval=100) 

# save the animation as mp4 video file 
#anim.save('test.gif',writer='imagemagick')
```

Also, i'm unable to slow down the animation by adjusting `interval`, all it does is increase the delay from when the animation starts, but doesn't slow the speed of the animation itself.

EDIT: i realize in the `animation()` function `i` isn't actually passed through anything... but if i replace it with df nothing plots at all. i'm pretty unfamiliar with this package

Comment: In the loop "subdf" the values do not change. Try to print "print(subdf)".
How do you want there to be movement, maybe in random order?

Comment: i can plot each animal's trajectory with ```import matplotlib.cm as cm

cmap = cm.get_cmap('rainbow')
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0.15, 0.85, df['animal'].nunique()))
color_map = dict(zip(df['animal'].unique(), colors))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for animal, subdf in df.sort_values('time').groupby('animal'):
    ax.plot(subdf['x'], subdf['y'], marker='o', label=animal, c=color_map[animal])
ax.legend()
plt.show()``` but my actual data has thousands of points and the figure is just one big mass. i want to be able to demonstratively show the trajectories of each animal with a gif instead

Comment: the movement is from one (x,y) coordinate to the next

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand what you want to get in this cycle:
"for animal, subdf in df.sort_values('time').groupby('animal'):"
And the values in this loop always remain the same, so there is no movement (animation). As far as I understand you, you need a trajectory of movement along three points, each time different. I made a random selection of three elements from df['x'] and df[y'] at each iteration. Look is this what you wanted to see?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

df ={'animal' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
     'x':[76.551, 77.529, 78.336,79.249,  76.077, 77, 78.02, 79.23, 77.733],
     'y': [151.933, 152.945, 153.970, 152.004, 153.027, 119.369, 120.615, 118.935, 119.115],
    'time': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3,2,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

x = df['x'].sample(n=3)
y = df['y'].sample(n=3)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(75, 80), ylim=(119, 155))
ax.plot(x, y, marker='o')

# initialization function
def init():
   pass

# animation function
def animate(i):
   x = df['x'].sample(n=3)
   y = df['y'].sample(n=3)
   ax.plot(x, y, marker='o')

# setting a title for the plot
plt.title('Animal animation')

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, interval=1000)

plt.show()
```

Comment: no. i don't want random points, i'm am plotting data from animal trajectories. each animal move along it's own path (given by the x,y coords). the ` for animal, subdf in df.sort_values('time').groupby('animal'):` is because i want to plot each individual animal's path according to time

Comment: if you run the code in my last comment, you'll see the plot i can make, now i want to animate it (i realize the formatting got messed up in the comment)